# How about supporting "Scroll To Text Fragment" URLs instead of escaping them?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

[Text location hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161819/what-exactly-is-the-text-location-hash-in-an-url) are useful when pasting a URL to a page without anchors.

Here are some live examples:

- [https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/pango_markup.html#:~:text=insert_hyphens](https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/pango_markup.html#:%7E:text=insert_hyphens)
- [https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.TextTag.html#properties:~:text=TextTag%3Ainsert%2Dhyphens](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.TextTag.html#properties:%7E:text=TextTag%3Ainsert%2Dhyphens)

These are escaped by Stack Overflow. When you directly click the link, the highlight doesn't work. A user has to copy the URL and paste to a browser location bar manually. In the edit preview it is fine, but in normal view mode, it is escaped: `:~:text` become `:%7E:text`, and the anchors ineffective.

Comment: I know this has been discussed previously, but I don't recall if there's a duplicate question. Prior experimentation indicated that such URLs do work in comments, but not posts.

Comment: Such URLs are *non-standard*. In fact, they specifically use reserved characters to have the additional `:~:text` delimiter. Such URLs are, currently, only supported in Chromium. I don't know if other browsers are moving to support them. That such URLs are not currently functional in posts is a bug/FR in Chromium, not Stack Exchange, IMO. What's preventing the URLs from being functional is that SE's backend percent encodes the `~` to `%7E`. That's perfectly valid and common. If Chromium wants to use `:~:text`, then Chromium should decode the `%7E`, which is *explicitly permitted*.

Comment: There is a comment in the linked suggested duplicate that says if you use an anchor tag instead of markdown, so `<a href="foo.com:~:text">foo</a>` instead of `[foo](foo.com:~:text)`, the tilde symbol is preserved and scroll to text fragments will work. Just tried it myself and it indeed works with anchor tags. See my test answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357228/299995

Comment: @Makyen but on stackoverflow, edit preview, normal view, comment view they don't have same behavior

Comment: @CaveJohnson that's good workaround, thanks

Comment: @yurenchen The edit preview, backend conversion for posts, backend conversion for comments, chat pre-conversion, and chat backend conversion all use different code and/or settings for Markdown -> HTML conversion. There's quite a number of discrepancies between how the all of them operate. While I agree that all of them *should be* nearly identical, they aren't. This is just yet one more way in which they aren't the same.